# What is the best way to encrypt private key, public key, seed?

Tags: ether

I have a app that generates public and private keys and address from a seed. Now, I'm trying to build a dashboard for the actual "account". In flutter, after generating private keys, public keys, and seed phrase where do I put it? MetaMask seems to store it in persistent storage after encrypting it. Is this the best way? I also want the user to unlock the wallet using biometrics, how does it fit into all this?

Comment: Some platforms like iOS, Android, Windows does provide a secure storage. Ethereum has a standard to store a private key as a JSON file https://onlino.gitbook.io/another_math_book/symmetric-key-ciphers/ethereum-wallet-encryption. Also you can use standard containers for storing cryptographic data like X509.